# How to check if any item is selected in JavaFX ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

What is the simple way to check whether any item is selected in JavaFX ComboBox or if it is left without selected item?

Checking for ComboBox in this state should return FALSE:
[image: ComboBox in this state should return FALSE]

Checking for ComboBox in this state should return TRUE:
[image: ComboBox in this state should return TRUE]

Comment: getSelectedItem return `null` if nothing is selected .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use

```
boolean isMyComboBoxEmpty = myComboBox.getSelectionModel().isEmpty();
```

Which also works, if you have a `null` item among the `ComboBox` items.

Answer (score 8):

So I found a simple way:

```
boolean isMyComboBoxEmpty = (myComboBox.getValue() == null);
```

Comment: You can use the itemProperty and bind a BooleanProperty to make it responsive. I dont know where the OP need the boolean for, though it might be handy.

Comment: You don't need a tenary expression to assign `true`, if `(myComboBox.getValue() == null)` yields `true` and `false` if `(myComboBox.getValue() == null)` yields `false`. Just use `boolean isMyComboBoxEmpty = (myComboBox.getValue() == null);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
!(cmbDia.getValue()==null) && !(cmbMes.getValue()==null) && !(cmbAno.getValue()==null)//fue todo gracias :)
```

Comment: Please add more clear code snippet with a proper comment to help others

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it